# How to proof the cone of Hausdorff space is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space, the cone $CX = X \times I / X \times \{0\}$, How to proof $CX$ is a Hausdorff space?

Answer (score 2):

If $v = (x, t), w = (y, t) \in CX$ are distinct points that have the same coordinate $t$ in $I$ then they are contained in the same $X$-slice (which cannot be the cone tip because $v$ and $w$ are distinct), so you can use that $X$ is Hausdorff to choose open disjoint sets $V, W$ in $X$ such that $x \in V$, $y \in W$. Then for $\epsilon$ small enough the cylinders $V \times B(t, \epsilon)$ and $W \times B(t, \epsilon)$ are open disjoint sets containing $v$ and $w$ respectively ($\epsilon$ just needs to be small enough that these sets don't intersect the cone tip). If $v$ and $w$ have different $t$ coordinates then you can just choose $X \times B(t_1, \epsilon)$ and $X \times B(t_2, \epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is small enough that the two sets are disjoint.